# Populate checkbox from database

Tags: php

I have two tables first one consist of id`s which are associated with names
1 - Car
2 - Train
3 - Plain
..etc

The second table consists of two fields user_id and an id from the first table (for example 1)
1 2
1 3

I`m trying to repopulate selected checkboxes when user goes to the page

Comment: May we see your try too? What is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you query the database for results, your query should look like this (fill in the correct table and column names):

```
SELECT user_id, t2.id, name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Then add the following to your PHP code. mind you: I have not tested this, so it's possible it needs some debug.

```
 $qry = "SELECT user_id, t2.id, name
        FROM table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id";
    $res = mysql_query($qry);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" + $row['name'] +"' checked='";
     if($row['user_id'] != NULL) echo "checked";
    echo "' />";
      }
```